# kendo ui grid angular 2 footer template

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-ui-grid

how to display the sum of a column in the footer of kendo grid for angular 2. i tried using the aggregateBy method like this

```
public sumUnitPrice() {
    return aggregateBy(this.gridView.data, [{ aggregate: "sum", field: "UnitPrice" }]);
}
```

but in the footer how to call this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example how to use [footerTemplate directive](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/FooterTemplateDirective/).

Similarly you can show the result of the `aggregateBy` function in the footer template - http://plnkr.co/edit/p8LpBRZmDO5jrhZ5U91w?p=preview